# How can i locate the elements of my app in inspector using appium in Mac OS X?

Tags: android, testng, appium, inspector, recorder

[image]I'm using inspector in appium with Android in Mac OS.
My problem is that i can't locate the element username for example correctly.
No red rectangle is been drawn while i want to know the xpath of username.
Shall i use SVG code ?

Comment: Did you try with UIAutomator? to inspect element?

Comment: i try UIAutomator in Windows it works fine, but now i'm in Mac OS i want to use recorder in order to get all the code for any scenario.
The problem in Mac inspector there is no red rectangle drawn automatically so i have to guess where is the element i want !

Comment: It should work fine in mac also. Can you share screenshot of inspector window?

Comment: OK, i have added a screenshot.

Comment: you should add screenshot by update your question. You have added as answer. Delete from answer.

Comment: OK thanks, i'm didn't post a question before with screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99695/discussion-between-emna-and-helping-hands).